# The requested resource is not available. Tomcat 7.0

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am new to J2EE I am trying to run a html file as a trial on my tomcat 7.0
typing the url http://localhost:8081/ successfully navigates me to the tomcat home page but when i try run my "dynamic web project" from eclipse which contains nothing but web.xml and index.html file, I am getting this error

HTTP Status 404 - /StudentManagement/

---

type Status report

message /StudentManagement/

description The requested resource is not available.

`web.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"; xmlns="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"; xsi:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"; id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>StudentManagement</display-name> 
    <welcome-file-list> 
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list> 
</web-app>
```

Comment: It's tough to say what's going wrong without seeing the `web.xml` file.

Comment: You have to configure the URL to your project. Check your web.xml.

Comment: **Here is my xml file**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>StudentManagement</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a welcome file set in your web.xml file then you have to specifically ask for the resource you want. In your case use `http://localhost:8081/StudentManagement/index.html`

Comment: Is your war file name appropriately? It should be `StudentManagement.war`

Comment: I have web.xml file here is my code here is my xml file.


`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>StudentManagement</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>`

localhost:8081/StudentManagement/index.html gives the same error –

Answer (score 0):

1. On your Tomcat configuration (modules tab in eclipse) 
   see which path is associated to your webapp
2. without servlet you have to declare explicitly a welcome file in the web.xml

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>StudentManagement</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>`

Comment: show us the structure of your project

Comment: <img src= "http://s3.postimg.org/aj23ynb4j/struct.jpg">

Comment: index should be in WebContent,  not in Web inf.

Comment: oh yes. Thank you "loxos" for helping me . now running successfully ...